# Part of an on click event only works on the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#comic").click(function(){
    nextPanel(comic);
});
```

nextPanel function:

```
function nextPanel(comic){

if(comic.panel <= comic.pos[comic.page-1].length/2){
    $('#panel_'+comic.page+'_'+comic.panel).css({display: "block"});
    comic.panel+=1;
    $("body").append("PING ");
}   
else if(comic.page+1 <= comic.pos.length){
    nextPage(comic);
    }

}
```

The "PING" message shows up just fine on the first click. But the element doesn't appear (it's set to "display: 'none'" as default) until the second click. What is going on here?

Comment: can you post the structure of the 'comic' object?  i'd guess that comic.panel is uninitialized, and won't match an element until incremented to 1 on the first click.

Comment: I think it's because `PING ` isn't a valid HTML element (probably the `display:none` is added by your browser). Could you try to wrap it inside an element instead (eg `<div>PING </div>`) ? Anyway, I'd suggest you use jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue and post the link here in order to help other understand your problem

Comment: Thanks, derelict! I found the problem. The panel propriety was pointing to an already displayed panel. All I had to fix do was to put  "comic.panel+=1;" one line above. I'm a goddamn idiot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change to this:

```
$("#comic").on('click',function(){
    nextPanel(comic);
});
```

This is because, maybe the element is not present in your DOM and you trying to do someting on it before exist. So if you do it like shown above, it might behave correctly.if that doesn't work try this below:

```
$("body").on('click', "#comic",function(){
    nextPanel(comic);
});
```

Comment: Your first suggestion with `$("#comic").on('click',function(){..})` will work exactly the same way as the OP's `$("#comic").click(function(){...})`. But in any case, we know the element *does* exist because clicking on it does call the `nextPanel()` function (question says the first click displays the "PING" message, and subsequent clicks work as expected), so the problem is not in how the click handler is bound.

Comment: Nope. It was like that before and I changed it around to see if it would make a difference. I didn't.